# .Net core entity framework LINQ expression couldn't be translated

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

When I am trying to use a props.getValue method in my where clause I get an an error. This error occurrers because LINQ cant translate the call of this method in SQL, because SQL doesnt know this method. I have read something about expression trees, but I dont really understand how to use them, so it would be nice if someone could explain me how to use them correct.

My method from a controller:

```
  int end = pageNumber * filter; int start = end - filter;
            var query = GetRequestsWithoutFilter().Where(r => r.RequestStatus == 1);

            if (attribute != null && title!=null)
            {
                if (attribute.Equals("movieReleaseDate"))
                {
                    int i = Int32.Parse(title);
                    query = query.Where(r => (r.Movie.MovieReleaseDate) == i);
                }
                else
                {
                    Movie m = new Movie();
                    PropertyInfo props = m.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => String.Equals(attribute, p.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (props!=null)
                    {
                        query = query.Where(r => ((string)props.GetValue(r.Movie)).Substring(0, (title.Length < r.Movie.MovieTitle.Length ? title.Length : r.Movie.MovieTitle.Length)).ToUpper().Equals(title));
                    }
                }
            }

            try { 
             var result = await query.Skip(start).Take(filter).ToListAsync();
                if (result == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return result;
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
            
        }
```

GetRequestsWithoutFilter:

```
 [NonAction]
        private IQueryable<Request> GetRequestsWithoutFilter()
        {
            IQueryable<Request> query = _context.Requests.Include(r => r.User)
                                                .Include(r => r.Movie)
                                                .Select(e => new Request()
                                                {
                                                    RequestID = e.RequestID,
                                                    MovieID = e.MovieID,
                                                    Movie = new Movie()
                                                    {
                                                        MovieID = e.MovieID,
                                                        MovieTitle = e.Movie.MovieTitle,
                                                        MovieDescription = e.Movie.MovieDescription,
                                                        MovieDirector = e.Movie.MovieDirector,
                                                        MovieProducer = e.Movie.MovieProducer,
                                                        ImageSrc = String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}/Images/Movies/{3}", Request.Scheme, Request.Host, Request.PathBase, e.Movie.ImageName),
                                                        MovieReleaseDate = e.Movie.MovieReleaseDate, 
                                                    },
                                                    UserID = e.UserID,
                                                    User = new User()
                                                    {
                                                        UserID = e.User.UserID,
                                                        UserVorname = e.User.UserVorname,
                                                        UserNachname = e.User.UserNachname
                                                    },
                                                    RequestDate = e.RequestDate,
                                                    RequestStatus = e.RequestStatus
                                                });
            return query;
        }
```

Movie model:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MoviesWebApi.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public Movie()
        {
            Requests = new HashSet<Request>();
        }


        [Key]
        public int MovieID { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(40)")]
        public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(1000)")]
        public string MovieDescription { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(40)")]
        public string MovieDirector { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(40)")]
        public string MovieProducer { get; set; }

        public int MovieReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string ImageName { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string ImageSrc { get; set; }

        public  ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can check the doc:[LINQ queries are no longer evaluated on the client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client).

Comment: Are you using EF6 or EF Core?

Comment: I am using EF Core

Answer (score 2):

Reflection calls like this

```
((string)props.GetValue(r.Movie))
```

as part of the query expression tree are not translatable.

What you have here is retrieving a value of a property. The expression equivalent of it is [`Expression.Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.property?view=net-5.0), but then you need to either construct the whole predicate using the `Expression` class methods, which is tedious and error prone, or use some helper utility for composing expressions.

It's not that hard, but in EF Core there is a simpler solution, since it provides a special method called [`EF.Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-5.0), which is recognized and properly translated.

In order to use it, all you need is to know the property name and **type**. The later is a bit problematic in dynamic scenarios, but luckily you seem to be targeting `string` type properties, so just replace the above with

```
EF.Property<string>(r.Movie, props.Name)
```